# about SIGALRM and alarm

Tags: linux, signals

There is something really puzzles me,the core codes is followed

```
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER+1];
    int ret;
    signal(SIGALRM,wakeup);
    printf("You have 3 seconds to enter the password\n");
    alarm(3);
    ret=read(0,buffer,MAX_BUFFER);
    alarm(0);
```

Could you tell me why there needs seconds alarm(0) here , what is this meaning?thank you!!!

Comment: You could sometimes use `poll` for such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there because you may enter the password in two seconds (for example), so you don't want an alarm going off one second after that. In other words, it turns *off* the alarm in the case where the thing you're trying to timeout actually finishes *before* the timeout occurs.

Doing an `alarm(0)` when no current alarm is active is harmless (other than the other problems such as interference with `sleep` and so on, but they're unimportant here).

However, having a rogue `SIGALRM` delivered when you're not expecting it may well cause some damage (such as if you've reset the `SIGALRM` handler to something else) so it's safer to disable it anyway, even if it's expired.